# Dispatch function call to other class with same interface in Java

Tags: java

I have two classes A and B which both implment the interface Z. Now, class A should for some functions of Interface Z (Z.f1, Z.f2, Z.f3, ...) only work as dispatcher to an object of class B.

```
public class A implements Z{

private B b;  //instantiated in constructor of A

@Override
public String f1(int p)
{
  return b.f1(p);
}
...
```

Is there a generic way to do this in Java?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "generic".  You've already got the pattern whereby A (the facade) gets a reference to the implementation (B) to which it needs to dispatch requests.  Are you asking for something to generate the dispatch methods for you?

Comment: Yes, possibly. Interface Z has about 50 methods and in most cases I just want to dispatch them in A to an instance of B. It could be a code snippet which I copy 'n paste into the IDE generated stubs or s.th. with reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that method `f1()` is declared in interface `Z` the pattern you want to implement is called wrapper or decorator.

In java you can create generic implementation using dynamic proxy introduced to java 1.4.

Comment: I'm not sure that somebody with 1 StackOverflow point wants to deal with dynamic proxies.  :-)  Is there a really good, simple tutorial on how to use them?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looking into that.
@user949300 I am new to stackoverflow, not Java or SW development in general. http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java looks like a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  But sometimes your IDE can assist in creating all the simple methods to delegate the calls.  And sometimes you can find third part classes to do this.  For example, Guava (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a ton of ForwardingXXX classes, which, by default, delegate everything to something else.  For example, ForwardingMap delegates all calls to another Map.  You need to override the methods that you do NOT want to delegate.